# Classifying website type from webpages

Tags: machine-learning, document-classification

Are there any reliable/deployed approaches, algorithms or tools to tagging the website type by parsing some its webpages.

For ex: forums, blogs, PressRelease sites, news, E-Comm etc.

I am looking for some well-defined characteristics (Static rules) from which this can be determined. If not, then i hope Machine Learning model may help.

Suggestions/Ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you approach this from machine learning standpoint, Naive Bayes classifier probably has the greatest work/payoff ratio. A version of it is used in [Winnow](http://winnowtag.org/) to categorize news articles.

You will need a collection of pages, each tagged with it's proper category. Then you extract words or other relevant elements from each page and use them as features

Dr.Dobbs has an [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/184406064) on implementing Naive Bayes

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in persuing the naïve Bayes approach (there are other machine learning options, after all), then I suggest the following document, which follows the coverage of this subject in "Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques", by Witten and Frank:

http://www.coli.uni-sb.de/~crocker/Teaching/Connectionist/lecture10_4up.pdf